# How to change the font color dynamically?

Tags: html, colors, jasper-reports, ireport

Here is my xml content:

```
span style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
```

This Background color comes along with my *Java* coding. As this background color is dynamic so whatever color may come in my report.

So my question is how to input the given color to *JasperReports*'s report using *iReport* with that dynamic color each time.

Eg: First time the color may be yellow, Next time the color may be orange and so on..

Comment: [Conditional Styles](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/jasper/index.html#conditionalstyles)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to pass you `color code` as parameter to `jasper report` and later use it in jasper report. Somewhat like following.
Declare following parameters:

```
<parameter name="r" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<parameter name="g" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<parameter name="b" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
```

Use it as follows:

```
span style="background-color: rgb("+$P{r}+", "+$P{g}+", "+$P{b}+")"
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Darshan, have you tried like this? or came across like this issue?

Comment: Not specifically the color issue, but there were several issues that required me to pass parameters and use them in report.